# CTE Missing Records

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

The first query listed below returns some logistical data associated with hires that have been made within a particular period of time. The query returns 478 records.

```
SELECT c.candidate_id AS candidate_id
,o.name 
,j.name AS job_title
,c.applied_from
,job_id AS job_id 
,cjs.score AS smart_rank_score
,cjs.is_completed AS smartrank_completion_status
,c.hired_at
FROM candidate_jobs c
LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = c.job_id
WHERE o.name LIKE ANY ('{"%Tutor Doctor%"}')
AND c.hired_at :: date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-02-22'
ORDER BY 8 DESC
```

However, when I attempted to add a CTE (see below) that displays each hire's final "post hire check in score", the query only returns 236 records. Ideally, I'd like the query to either return a score or null value for each of the initial 478 hire records.

```
WITH final_post_hire_score (candidate_id, final_score) AS
(SELECT c.candidate_id
  ,p.score 
  FROM post_hire_followup_reviews p 
  LEFT JOIN candidate_jobs c ON c.id = p.candidate_job_id 
  WHERE p.check_in_number = 3)

SELECT c.candidate_id AS candidate_id
,o.name 
,j.name AS job_title
,c.applied_from
,job_id AS job_id 
,cjs.score AS smart_rank_score
,cjs.is_completed AS smartrank_completion_status
,c.hired_at
,final_score
FROM final_post_hire_score f
LEFT JOIN candidate_jobs c ON c.candidate_id = f.candidate_id
LEFT JOIN organizations o ON o.id = c.organization_id
LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = c.job_id
WHERE o.name LIKE ANY ('{"%Tutor Doctor%"}')
AND c.hired_at :: date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-02-22'
ORDER BY 8 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing records are due to the filter's, Move the filter's to `ON` condition else your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`

When you are using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` *right table* filter's should be present in `ON` condition else the `NULL` values for non matching records will get filtered

```
WITH final_post_hire_score (candidate_id, final_score)
     AS (SELECT c.candidate_id,
                p.score
         FROM   post_hire_followup_reviews p
                LEFT JOIN candidate_jobs c
                       ON c.id = p.candidate_job_id
         WHERE  p.check_in_number = 3)
SELECT c.candidate_id   AS candidate_id,
       o.NAME,
       j.NAME           AS job_title,
       c.applied_from,
       job_id           AS job_id,
       cjs.score        AS smart_rank_score,
       cjs.is_completed AS smartrank_completion_status,
       c.hired_at,
       final_score
FROM   final_post_hire_score f
       LEFT JOIN candidate_jobs c
              ON c.candidate_id = f.candidate_id
             AND c.hired_at :: date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-02-22'
       LEFT JOIN organizations o
              ON o.id = c.organization_id
             AND o.NAME LIKE ANY ( '{"%Tutor Doctor%"}' )
       LEFT JOIN candidate_job_surveys cjs
              ON cjs.candidate_job_id = c.id
       LEFT JOIN jobs j
              ON j.id = c.job_id
ORDER  BY 8 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an extra

```
WHERE p.check_in_number = 3
```

that isn't anywhere else.

Comment: I mean, it's in your CTE, but it's not in the original query.